# Добавление ImageView

Tags: android

Хочу добавить 2 ImageView, именно программным способом, таким образом, чтобы один был под другим. Но при добавлении элемента point он перекрывает объект ball, a не наоборот. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mainlayout"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">
    </TextView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); //блокировка ориентации
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON); //не гасить экран

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE); // Получаем менеджер сенсоров
    mAcceleration = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER); // Получаем датчик ускорения

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
    float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;

    dpBallHeight = (int) dpHeight - 50;
    dpBallWidth = (int) dpWidth - 50;

    // Добавляем ImageView Point
    point = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
    point.setImageResource(R.drawable.point);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams pointLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
    pointLayoutParams.setMargins(dpBallWidth, dpBallHeight,0,0);
    point.setLayoutParams(pointLayoutParams);

    // Добавляем ImageView Ball
    ball = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
    ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.sphere);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams ballLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
    ballLayoutParams.setMargins(dpBallWidth, dpBallHeight,0,0);
    ball.setLayoutParams(ballLayoutParams);



    mainLayout.addView(point);
    mainLayout.addView(ball);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю можно перед добавлением в макет виджетов добавить предварительно какой-то LinearLayout или другой контейнер, куда потом положить ваши виджеты. Добавить программно контейнер можно так:

```
LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(context);

parent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

//children of parent linearlayout

ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);

LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(context);

layout2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
layout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

parent.addView(iv);
parent.addView(layout2);

//children of layout2 LinearLayout

TextView tv1 = new TextView(context);
TextView tv2 = new TextView(context);
TextView tv3 = new TextView(context);
TextView tv4 = new TextView(context);

layout2.addView(tv1);
layout2.addView(tv2);
layout2.addView(tv3);
layout2.addView(tv4);
```

Это пример выше, в вашем случае нужно определить ориентацию контейнера, если вы его будете использовать, и заполнить виджетами. Так же можно использовать RalativeLayout:

```
// Creating a new RelativeLayout
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

// Defining the RelativeLayout layout parameters.
// In this case I want to fill its parent
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

// Creating a new TextView
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Test");

// Defining the layout parameters of the TextView
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

// Setting the parameters on the TextView
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

// Adding the TextView to the RelativeLayout as a child
relativeLayout.addView(tv);

// Setting the RelativeLayout as our content view
setContentView(relativeLayout, rlp);
```

[вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979212/how-to-create-a-relativelayout-programmatically-with-two-buttons-one-on-top-of-t) подобный вопрос есть.